# SCP from Remote Server to Windows Local Machine

Tags: ssh, scp, file-copy

I would like to copy files from a remote Unix machine to a local Windows machine.  The remote machine requires a secure connection, and therefore the default Windows tools, such as FTP, don't work.  I can run `ssh` on the local machine to log into the remote machine, but I am not able to run anything to copy the remote files to the local machine, since the local machine doesn't have `scp`.  Is there a way to copy them while `ssh`ed into the remote machine?  For example, by setting up a pipe to receive the contents of the remote file and save it onto the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is a graphical file transfer utility for Windows that supports both scp and (by default) sftp, in addition to other file transfer protocols.

Comment: And the [author](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119732/martin-prikryl) is a user of this site!

Answer (score 0):

If you have python on your windows machine, you can try this:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh4py

If you do not have python, simpler approach is to install putty Scp

https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-putty

Answer (score 0):

If you install [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) that includes a command-line `pscp` utility, which is PuTTY's equivalent of `scp`.  Documentation on how to use `pscp` is [here.](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.73/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp)